# Removing Duplicate Code From Simple Methods - Going too far?

Tags: c#, oop, dry

I have a WCF service with many (~30) methods like this:

```
public Foo GetFooById(string id)
{
    try
    {
        return FooLogic.GetById(id);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw LogAndThrowFaultException(ex);
    }
}
```

The code in these methods is exactly the same except for the one line in the try block. This is about as simple as it gets, and I've even already abstracted logging and throwing an exception.

In the spirit of DRY, I could go even further and do this:

```
public Foo GetFooById(string id)
{
    return PerformServiceOperation<Foo>(() => FooLogic.GetById(id));
}
```

For this to work, this method would handle the duplicate try/catch code and invoke each func:

```
private T PerformServiceOperation<T>(Func<T> func)
{
    try
    {
        return func.Invoke();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw LogAndThrowFaultException(ex);
    }
}
```

Is this going too far? Was the code already as simple as it gets and should it be left alone? Or is it a good idea to pass the func to the helper method and let that method deal with the repetitive try/catch? I'm concerned with readability as well. I think the call to the helper method is a bit ugly.

Comment: DRY is not an end in of itself; it's purpose is to *lower the cost of maintenance*. How much are you paid an hour to make this change, and how much money will making this change save you in the long run?  I'd call this a waste of your valuable time; spend your valuable time writing test cases or reviewing specifications or implementing new features or writing a performance monitoring tool; all those things will have a larger return on investment.

Comment: What Eric said.  Your "In the spirit of DRY" example was already DRY; all you did was add some additional ceremony to it.

Comment: I agree with @EricLippert. Also this level of abstraction is only going to make your code harder to read and therefore harder to maintain. No pattern, principle or methodology is set in stone. Just use them when they make sense and stop once you reach a point of diminishing (or even negative!) returns.

Comment: This is a misunderstanding of DRY. The context of The Pragmatic Programmer is that all programming is maintenance programming. If you refer to The Pragmatic Programmer, you'll see that DRY is *not* necessarily about duplicating code. DRY is about not repeating a piece of knowledge with the effect of reducing maintenance costs. In this case, there's no piece of knowledge being repeated, and you are arguably *increasing* maintenance costs. Finally, there are other principles, such as KISS. They are not always in concert with each other. Here, you're violating KISS in an attempt to be DRY.

Comment: DRY violations are like weeds... yes, a single weed won't ruin a garden, but the thing about weeds is that they don't remain alone for long.

Comment: It's funny; I shared this question with some folks at work, and it was almost unanimous that I should abstract the try/catch. The reason: not repeated in 20 methods, able to eventually inject other exception handling in just one spot, and it's clean. Good points.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd have to say that in general, in production code I tend to think DRY should be taken to an extreme.  I have a few reasons I've developed over a couple decades.

1) "Fixes" in one place get propagated.  A simple fix like this one you suggest could save hours of QA bouncing your code as one after another method fail a simple test.  This is perhaps an extreme case but I've seen it happen.  Also although YOU know that this code is reproduced and you have to make fixes in multiple places, does the next engineer just KNOW this?

By the way, a viable alternative is to document each place code is duplicated to reference the other locations so the maintainer knows where to go.

2) Programmer ability.  By insisting on absolutely 0 code duplication you will learn techniques that will make you a better engineer.  There is a lot of code I've seeen where The enginner insisted they couldn't make it any more dry--yet I'd done it myself a dozen times (perhaps with a trick like the one you used here) because I'd had to puzzle it out at some point.

3) Probably the least obvious and yet most important--Iterative Refactoring.  Refactoring can often only be done in layers.  You have certainly looked at a bunch of messy, incomprehsible code and only seen the most minor of refactorings--yet after refactoring those others become clear and those enable others.  I've taken huge methods that everyone was afraid to touch and taken them down to 1/10 of their original size this way.

4) Data extraction.  If you insist on DRY, you end up with a lot of batches of data because one of the most basic refactorings is to extract different data from similar code then combine the code.  This makes your code much more maintainable--in the past I've often been able solve a problem with a change to a string array when before the refactor it generally took hours or days.

I've had to convince people of this everywhere I've been (You can see this just by looking at the number of people saying "No" to this question).  Extreme DRY is generally a tough sell in the beginning--until they see the results.  I think the most important thing you can do personally is commit to being as DRY as your talent will let you (Which gets to be MUCH more as you practice).

IF the particular refactor you listed turns out to cause problems, well, you've learned something and can approach it differently next time.  You learned and the time wasn't wasted.

You will, by the way, learn that it's critical to write your extremely DRY code in a way that is understandable and usable by others--this isn't always easy and can cause some people to hate "refactoring" and "over-engineering" until they figure out that the person who's code they were working on just wasn't good enough at communication (through code).

PS: I should have mentioned another one--because coding DRY is FUN.  Copying and pasting code (and fixing that code) is the most miserable work you can do as a programmer, but creating short, DRY code that is still usable and maintainable is a mental challenge, a puzzle that any engineer worth his salt should enjoy.

Comment: Fantastic. I'm going to share this. Thank you.

Comment: By the way, in XP this principle is called "Ruthless Refactoring" and is considered required--without it a small agile team will have ever-increasing difficulty maintaining an evolving codebase.

Comment: Excellent answer, couldn't agree more.

Answer (score 2):

Conceptually, I don't thnk that is going too far at all. Change the way you handle your exceptions just once, and you will be glad you decided not to type the same try-catch blocks over and over and over. I would be more inclined to handle exceptions through an aspect, but your solution is viable as well.

Answer (score 0):

> Going too far?

Notice that you **add** a call to PerformServiceOperation() in each method in order to move exception handling out of the method. Unless you save a lot of maintenance time from duplicate exception handling, you might be going to far.

However, if there is already a way to add exception handling to your framework of choice (WCF) to handle unhandled exceptions, then it wouldn't be too far to do it that way.

Method interception for logging exceptions is very simple using [aspect oriented programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect_oriented_programming) (AOP). But it's certainly too far to switch to AOP for this sole reason...